# How can I create a display for tracking employee schedules in SharePoint?

Tags: list, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

Recently my workplace has requested for employees to announce what times and when they're coming into the office. As a courtesy for other team members and and to meke more in person meetings possible.

My team of about 8 members wants to utilize SharePoint as a means for keeping track of this, Here's a general overivew of the data we'd

| Name | Monday In | Monday Out | Monday Location | Tuesday In | Tuesday Out | Tuesday Location | Wednesday In | Wednesday out | Wednesday Location | e.t.c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 8:30 | 5:00 | In Office | 7:00 | 4:00 | 7:00 | 5:00 | Remote | ... | ... |
| alice | 7:00 | 4:00 | Remote | 6:00 | 6:00 | 8:00 | 5:30 | In office | ... | ... |
| tim | " | " | " | " | " | " | " | " | " |  |
| Billy | " | " |  | " | " | " | " | " | " |  |

Even with 8 team members this would restult in a lot of dense information to comb though if you just wanted to know the status of One team member tomorrow. This list isn't concrete either, It's a general guide for other colleagues to know.

Is there a Way to have SharePoint display this information in a easy human readable way? Perhaps as a collection of cards for each team member or Simply a filter for One employee

The information in the tables is a little too information dense for a quick heads up when someone wants to just know if team member X will be in the office on Tuesday.

We also use teams and outlook. I've considered configuring the in/out times then but as far as i can't see you cannot query the information an end user puts in.